# Yet Another Forum integration with Umbraco issue

Tags: forum, umbraco, yetanotherforum

I have been integrating YAF with Umbraco using the following guide:

http://dawoe.blogspot.com/2009/02/intergrate-yet-another-forum-193rc2.html

I used the latest version of YAF (1.9.4) and umbraco 4. However as mentioned in that page, there is a known issue with the user registration. Anyone knows how to get around that?

Comment: How were you able to get to that point?  I can't even get my forums to load.

Comment: It works now. I can't remember how I did it, but yeah, it does work.

Comment: This one should have been answered some time ago. I'm going to answer it to hopefully close it off.

Answer (score 0):

Taken from the forums - it's the web.config that often breaks the site when installing. YAF installs it's own web.config and app.config that need to be merged with a backup of your web.config.

1. Backup your web.config before installing
2. Merge the <appSettings /> section of your web.config backup with <appSettings /> found in the app.config file that YAF installs.
3. Use the <pages /> section from the YAF web.config. to merge with your web.config's one. You can usually overwrite your web.config section except you must ensure that you have the section titled "umbraco" kept from yours.
4. Make sure defaultMemberTypeAlias is set to "Registered User"